# Checking whether a given Email address has Salesforce account

Tags: contact, python

I have an email address say abc@xyz.com.  I want to know If there is a Salesforce user(need not be in my organization) who has a salesforce account with abc@xyz.com as email. If such a salesforce account exists I would like to add it into my contacts.

Is there a possible way to determine whether a given email address has a Salesforce account using python?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to be an employee of salesforce.com to be able to look up a user by email address. Developers like myself would have many accounts by the same email (different usernames, of course), but you can't get at this information from the outside. Even trying to create new users by a particular email may yield a false positive or false negative, since they could be inactive and/or use a different email than username.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you would be best off using an anonymous APEX script to accomplish this task.

If you want to use python, you would have to export the data first.

Comment: I have this as a sub-problem of a project in python. So that's why.

Comment: Well, if you are going to use an external program to perform this operation in salesforce, you are going to have to use web-services. I would consider creating this functionality as an APEX class, and then exposing it with the @webservice annotation, which you could then call from your other program using the SOAP api.

Comment: I am new to development in salesforce. So can you tell me the logic involved  in knowing whether the email address is already a salesforce account or libraries that help in achieving this purpose in apex.

Comment: You would want to do a query on the standard sobject User to retrieve the email field.

Comment: Also, I know I just recommended the SOAP api, but I haven't personally built web-services with salesforce using python, so I don't know for sure what would be easiest.

Comment: By user I do not mean sobject user (i.e. user in my organization)but a salesforce user. the Salesforce user may not be a user in my organization. I have updated my question.

Comment: @SasiKiran If you are asking to check other Salesforce orgs (that you don't have access to) for Users and add them as Contacts to your own org, that is not possible.